# Why i can not define two def by clicked?

Tags: python, pyside, maxscript

I'm trying to do the Project follow some guy on forum, but when i use clicked function to link the first def with the second def, my purpose is how can i link 2 def each other, and the second def can understand the function in first def.
This is my code

```
def addnewobject():
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.setFixedSize(450,90)
    w.setWindowTitle('Select folder of new objects')
    _GCProtector.widgets.append(w)
    w.show()

    frameStyle = QtGui.QFrame.Sunken | QtGui.QFrame.Panel
    folder_lb = QtGui.QLabel("Folder : ")
    directoryLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
    directoryLabel.setFrameStyle(frameStyle)
    browse_btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Browse...")
    ex_lb = QtGui.QLabel("( ex : SCH, faucet, K7 )")
    cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
    ok_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")

    browser = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    browser.addWidget(folder_lb,0,0)
    browser.addWidget(directoryLabel,0,1,1,4)
    browser.addWidget(browse_btn,0,5)
    browser.addWidget(ex_lb,1,0,1,5)
    browser.addWidget(cancel_btn,2,4)
    browser.addWidget(ok_btn,2,5)
    browser.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
    w.setLayout(browser)

    browse_btn.clicked.connect(setExistingDirectory)
    cancel_btn.clicked.connect(w.close)

def setExistingDirectory():
    options = QtGui.QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory("QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()",directoryLabel.text(), options)
    if directory:
        directoryLabel.setText(directory)
```

I use browse_btn to link from addnewobject to setExistingDirectory to define directoryLabel, but it can not work.

Comment: A 'def' is called a 'function' (in Python, 'def' is shorthand for 'define function'). Anyway, 'it doesn't work' is not enough information - are you getting an error message, or does it simply not do anything when you press the button, or...? And what do you mean with the second function 'understanding' the first function?

Comment: I mean is when i use code above, it can not work. The error is : it can not define the directionLabel.

Answer (score 1):

`directionLabel` is a local variable inside `addnewobject`, so `setExistingDirectory` cannot access it. You have to store a reference to that label in a place where both functions can 'see' it.

If these functions are inside a class, then use a member variable (by prefixing it with `self.`). This is the approach that I would recommend:

```
class MyApplication:
    def addnewobject(self):
        # (...)
        self.directionLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        # (...)
        browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.setExistingDirectory)

    def setExistingDirectory(self):
        # (...)
        self.directoryLabel.setText('Test')
```

If they're top-level functions, then a global variable will do:

```
directionLabel = None

def addnewobject():
    global directionLabel
    # (...)
    directionLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
    # (...)

def setExistingDirectory():
    directoryLabel.setText('Test')
```

That, or you can pass a reference to `setExistingDirectory` by using a closure, in this case an anonymous function (`lambda`) that 'captures' the `directoryLabel` variable and passes it on to `setExistingDirectory` as an argument.

```
def addnewobject():
    # (...)
    browse_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: setExistingDirectory(directoryLabel))

def setExistingDirectory(label):
    # (...)
    label.setText('Test')
```